# Transform attribute in commented out xml

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

I want to transform a comment that i know is valid xml. For example, below I want to change the value of the bar attribute from x to y.

```
<root><!-- <foo bar="x"/> --></root>
```

The stylesheet I've created is below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment()">
        <xsl:comment>
            <xsl:variable name="xml-string">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="xml-node" select="exslt:node-set($xml-string)" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$xml-node" />
        </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@bar[parent::foo]">
        <xsl:attribute name="bar">
            <xsl:value-of select="'y'" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but the output I get from this is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><!-- <foo bar="x"/> --></root>
```

I suspect that the node-set function isn't actually doing what i thought it would.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You would need to use XSLT 3.0 and `parse-xml` to start with, and then you also need to explain whether the result should contain a `foo` element node or again a comment. In the latter case you also need the `serialize` function from XSLT 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, without any extension functions, you would have to do it in two steps:

First, apply the following stylesheet to your input XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and save the result to a file. Then process the resulting file with a second XSLT.

Note that not all processors support `disable-output-escaping`.

---

### Added:

It needs to be said that you're being sent on a fool's errand here. Once you have commented out XML, it is no longer XML and cannot be processed as such without some major jumping through hoops.

Similarly, if you expect the result to be a comment containing the original "XML" after processing, you are looking at another [painful and complicated process](http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/).

It's true that XSLT 3.0 makes both conversions easier. Still, the correct solution to this problem lies with the original document's author.

Comment: Even once it's been processed with a second XSLT you still won't have the modified element as a comment, unless you can output `<!--` using DOE, but I'm not sure that would work.

Comment: @Flynn1179 I am not sure that's a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The content of a comment isn't considered XML- you're right, the node-set function doesn't do this. You'd need the parse and serialize functions from XSLT3 if you really wanted to do that.

You can manipulate the value of the comment with string manipulation, there's probably 100's of examples of replacing a value in text within XSL on here already.

With your specific example here, you could just do `translate($xml-string,'x','y')`, but I suspect your real problem is more complex than that!

Comment: You're thinking of XSLT 3.0. You cannot do this in XSLT 2.0 - at least not directly or without extensions.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that later, couldn't remember at what point these were added.